# Django + Disable Caching for extended viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to disable Django Cacheing for one of the viewset in below scenario ? I want to disable caching for viewset with name SecondViewSet, I am using @method_decorator(never_cache, name="list") on SecondViewSet it is not working, kindly advise

**Abstract Viewset**

```
class AbstractDataViewSet(ListAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'options']
    permission_classes = [IsAuthorizedUser]

    @method_decorator(cache_page(settings.VIEWSET_CACHE_TIMEOUT))
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"message":"appdata"}
```

**First Viewset**

```
class FirstViewSet(AbstractDataViewSet):
    group_permissions = {
        'GET': (
            roles.ACCOUNTING,
        )
    }
```

**Second Viewset**

```
class SecondViewSet(AbstractDataViewSet):
    group_permissions = {
        'GET': (
            roles.ACCOUNTING,
        )
    }
```

**Third Viewset**

```
class ThirdViewSet(AbstractDataViewSet):
    group_permissions = {
        'GET': (
            roles.ACCOUNTING,
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the decorator appropriately uses `functools.wraps` or similar, you should be able to access the `__wrapped__` attribute and, effectively, undo the decorator.

```py
class SecondViewSet(AbstractDataViewSet):
    list = AbstractDataViewSet.list.__wrapped__
```

Alternatively, you can have another method separate from the decorated method that you delegate to from your `list` method. Then, simply redefine the method in the subclass to define it without the decorator.

```py
class AbstractDataViewSet(ListAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'options']
    permission_classes = [IsAuthorizedUser]
    def _list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"message":"appdata"}
    @method_decorator(cache_page(settings.VIEWSET_CACHE_TIMEOUT))
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._list(request, *args, **kwargs)

...

class SecondViewSet(AbstractDataViewSet):
    # define list again to avoid caching decorator
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

These approaches should work without having to change the implementation of the decorator. Another approach might be to change the implementation of the decorator to inspect class attributes to determine which methods should be cached.